# VBA-M, Configure spped

Tags: configuration, emulation

I am using VBA-M to play some games. Everything is working fine, but I would like to increase the speed in some of them. They are running with their "real" speed, but I would really lime if I could set the default speed at 200% instead.
Has anyone figured out a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Options -> FrameSkip -> Throttle -> 200%

[image: menu]

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately my VBA-M doesn't look like that. The "Throttle" option is not anywhere to be found..

Comment: Which version are you running? In addition, can you post a screenshot of your version?

Comment: Actually I figured something out. I just had to edit the .cfg file, and set the throttle there. Works perfectly now. Thanks for taking an interest anyway!!